# Dtrace String Comparison in predicate don't work

Tags: dtrace

I'm fairly new to dtrace. I'm using it on Oracle Linux 7.

I want the following probe only to fire when the execname equals a defined string. I've tried different ways without success. The way described in most tutorials didn't work

```
syscall::write*:entry
/execname=="dtrace"/
{
 ...
```

This doesn't work.

But the other way around works

```
syscall::write*:entry
/execname!="dtrace"/
{
 ...
```

Now the probe fires for every execname except "dtrace"

What's my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know how but a reboot fixed the problem...